# Relative Layout alignParentLeft vs alignParentStart

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So I am comfortable with using relative layouts, but whilst getting used to Android Studio I noticed that in my relative layout child views it generated both of the following.

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true
```

I have checked out the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html), but cannot see a distinction between the two. Certainly swapping one for another in the Android Studio shows no visible difference. Is there one?

Comment: I could never find any visible difference.

Comment: yes, change language to any RTL language and you will see

Comment: @selvin: What do you mean? I would also like to know this.

Comment: @Selvin, of course it makes perfect sense. I remember now that standard Java brought something like that in the early 00s. So start is start of page. Thanks for that. Do you want to make an official response so I can mark it?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I think what Selvin means is that it supports right to left languages such as Arabic where the start of the page is actually the right side. So if you used this in your layout, your app would provide this functionality, aligning right for right to left languages and aligning left for the likes of English, French and Spanish etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on the layout direction. The layout direction can be either left-to-right (start = left, end = right), or right-to-left (vice versa).

By default, the layout direction is based on the locale (left-to-right for languages like English, right-to-left for languages like Arabic), but you can override it with the [layoutDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection) XML attribute or [setLayoutDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutDirection(int)) function. e.g.:

```
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

^ will make alignParentStart equivalent to alignParentLeft on all devices.

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

^ will make alignParentStart equivalent to alignParentRight on all devices. You can also set to "locale" to use the locale or "inherit" to inherit the layout direction from the parent view.

You need to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to your AndroidManifest.xml to support right-to-left layouts.

also related: [android:textDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection)

Answer (score 6):

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

Aligns the *start* edge of *this* view to the *start* edge of its parent. This is the *left* edge for LTR (left to right) locales and the *right* one on RTL (right to left) locale languages like Arabic, Hebrew, Persian etc.

The reason Android Studio also adds

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

to your views is to support older platforms that came before 4.2.x `Jelly Bean`. The *Start/End* attributes like  `layout_alignParentStart` are only available from API 17 onwards. The newer platforms fallback to *Left/Right* attributes only if the corresponding *Start/End* attributes are not found.

In case, your application supports legacy platforms using `android:minSdkVersion` below level `17` you must always provide *Left/Right* attributes for your views. Otherwise the project won't compile with an error message like

> To support older versions than API 17 (project specifies 7)
>   you should also add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

Also note that your Android application needs to declare its support for RTL locales within your `AndroidManifest.xml` as well.

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

These "xxxStart", "xxxEnd" attribute is to  support RTL(Right to Left) layout in some locales.
Such as

```
android:paddingStart
android:paddingEnd
android:layout_marginStart
android:layout_marginEnd
...
```

You can see [more here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) about it.

In normal(left to right) layout, "xxxStart" means "xxxLeft" and "xxxEnd" means "xxxRight".But in Right to Left layout, "xxxStart" means "xxxRight" and "xxxEnd" means "xxxLeft".

But RTL is only supported on sdk 17 and higher.

To support lower sdk, you can use "android:layout_marginStart" along with "android:layout_marginLeft". At the lower sdk devices, "android:layout_marginLeft" will be used.

Comment: Good point about support on Android 17 or higher, that's the sort of useful information I like.