# alignParent - Left/Start and Right/End

Tags: android

Why when I add any widget and perform alignment operations on it, two options are automatically added, for example:

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

When using a version older than API 17 I should use:

`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` or

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Is there any way that only one option appears, not two? So you don't have to delete it manually? Or maybe you can leave both options and it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27934670/11996110) that explains the differences between

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true
```

In summary, `layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` are equivalent when the layout direction is left-to-right. They will be opposite to each other if the direction is right-to-left. By default the layout direction is based on the language, but it is possible to override it. For a language like English both statements accomplish the same result, so it's harmless if you leave both of them.